# The biggest answer ever, maybe

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

> Yew 
>  Knead 
>  It's 
>  Vane 
>  Urn 
>  Wrapped 
>  Strait,
>   don't 
>  You?

Don't be mislead, it sounds like you're on the right track.

Comment: Are you sure those last two words are right? (with Strait and don't on one line)

Comment: @randal'thor Yup it's right

Comment: [Hmph](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=You+need+its+vain+earn+rapt+straight), that wasn't much use.

Comment: Google will be of no use to you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is-

> **UNIVERSE**

The phrase can be said as

> U NEED ITS VAIN EARN RAPPED STRAIGHT EWE*
>
>  Taking first letters of each gives **UNIVERSE**
>
>  **Note**- I am not sure if we need to make any meaningful sentence as its not clued in there, hence this gibberish sentence.

Also

> The title confirms the answer.

Comment: Don't be mislead was supposed to tip you off to ignore don't as it is just readability and sounds like was supposed to tip off the homophones... Dang that was fast...

Comment: But I will say the ending is not supposed to be Err*, I'll give you a tick when you get the right last letter, otherwise spot on

Comment: @n_palum Hmm.. What could *You* or *don't You* mean...thinking...

Comment: Don't overthink it, you have the letter already

Comment: @n_palum I need to come up with a word that starts with E right? It could be Enigma/Else/End etc..

Comment: Just use the same thing you have been using for other words - none of those guesses are correct

Comment: @n_palum Ah. Right. Got it.

Comment: I'd say RAPT instead of RAPPED. Otherwise, nice answer.